# Solution for maximum xor secondary in an array of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, xor

I am trying to solve this codeforces problem

```
 http://codeforces.com/contest/281/problem/D
```

Given an array of integers, find the maximum xor of the first and second max element in any of the sub sequences ?

I am not able to figure out the optimal approach to solve this problem. Few of the solving techniques I articulated was using **sorting, stack** but I could not figure out the right solution.

I googled and found out the problem setter's code for the solution. But I could not understand the solution as it is in c++ and I am naive to it.

Below is the problem setter's code in c++

```
using namespace std;
using namespace io;

typedef set<int> Set;
typedef set<int, greater<int> > SetRev;

namespace solution {
  const int SIZE = 100000 + 11;
  int n;
  int A[SIZE];
  II S[SIZE];

  Set P;
  SetRev P_rev;

  int result;
}

namespace solution {
  class Solver {
  public:
      void solve() {
        normalize();
        result = get_maximum_xor();
      }

      int get_maximum_xor() {
        int res = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          int current_value = S[i].first;
          Set::iterator it_after = P.upper_bound(S[i].second);
          Set::iterator it_before = P_rev.upper_bound(S[i].second);

          if (it_after != P.end()) {
            int after_value = A[*it_after];
            res = max(res, current_value ^ after_value);
          }

          if (it_before != P_rev.end()) {
            int before_value = A[*it_before];
            res = max(res, current_value, before_value);
          }  

          P.insert(S[i].second);
          P_rev.insert(S[i].second);
        } 

        return res;
      }

      void normalise() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            S[i] = II(A[i], i);
        }
        sort(S, S + n, greater<II>());
      } 


}
```

Can someone please explain me the solution, the approach used as I understand it in pieces and not totally ?

Comment: Important rule at SO. Don't post images of code. Post the code.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will change it in a while

Comment: Don't post code as a screenshot, instead use pastebin or something else. About the problem, you should probably try stepping through your code with a debugger, and see where it does not do what you would expect or want

Comment: @RSahu edited .

Comment: @MivVG Yes ofcourse that would be the last thing I would do. But it would be helpful if some c++ expert can decipher the solution and state the approach

Comment: @MivVG I recommend against pastebin. Everything needed to interpret and answer the question must be in the question. A link to pastebin is lost and the question would become useless as soon as pastebin shuffles it's links, garbage collects, or gets turned into an adult site.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I have to agree with that, will take it with me for next time

Comment: @MivVG Yes I agree but I am not well versed in c++ as I code in java. It would take quite an effort for me. It would be really helpful if someone can pitch in

Comment: MivVG  is bang on right even if you did not write the code and are instead trying to figure out how it works. Fire up the debugger and step though the code just like you would debugging a program in Java. See what the program does. Take notes. Ask questions based on what the notes don't explain.

Comment: @AarishRamesh If you know Java, I don't think there is anything different in terms of programming. I guess you don't know the meaning of `P.end()`, `S[i].second`, etc ??

Comment: Exactly that's is what I don't understand @liliscent

Comment: @AarishRamesh Comparing with `.end()` is to check whether it is found. `Set` is sorted. `upper_bound` is to find the first element that > key. `*iter` is to get the key.... It's too broad to explain. I think you can guess the algorithm based on these information.

Comment: @MivVG See you can debug, analyse and fix “every” problem you encounter. But then there’s no point of stackoverflow and the concept of developers helping other developers in overcoming roadblocks they hit. Please rework on understanding the philosophy of SO before answering in such a generic way to any of the questions in the future. I have helped a lot of developers here and my question is sensible with good amount of ground work done

Comment: Take a look in alternative solution [here](http://gautamimp.blogspot.com/2016/02/d-maximum-xor-secondary-find-max-and.html), which uses a stack (probably the one you already mention in your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so `Solver::solve()` starts by calling `normalise`:

```
  void normalise() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        S[i] = II(A[i], i);
    }
    sort(S, S + n, greater<II>());
  }
```

What that's doing is taking an array `A` of integers - say `{4, 2, 9}`, and populating an array `S` where `A`'s values are sorted and paired with the index at which they appear in `A` - for our example, `{{2, 1}, {4, 0}, {9, 2}}`.

Then the solver calls  `get_maximum_xor()`...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int current_value = S[i].first;
      Set::iterator it_after = P.upper_bound(S[i].second);
      Set::iterator it_before = P_rev.upper_bound(S[i].second);
```

The "for i" loop is used to get successive sorted values from `S` (those values originally from `A`).  While you haven't posted a complete program, so we can't know for sure nothing's prepopulating any values in `P`, I'll assume that.  We do know `P`'s is a `std::map` and [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) searches to find the first element in `P` greater than `S[i].second` (the index at which `current_value` appeared in `A`) and values above, then something similar for `P_rev` which is a `std::map` in which values are sorted in descending order, likely it will be kept populated with the same values as `P` but again we don't have the code.

Then...

```
      if (it_after != P.end()) {
        int after_value = A[*it_after];
        res = max(res, current_value ^ after_value);
      }
```

...is saying that if any of the values in `P` were `>=` `S[i].second`, look up `A` at the index `it_after` found (getting a sense now that `P` tracks the last elements in each subsequence (?)), and if the `current_value` XORed with that value from `A` is more than any earlier result candidate (`res`), then update `res` with the new larger value.

It does something similar with `P_rev`.

Finally...

```
      P.insert(S[i].second);
      P_rev.insert(S[i].second);
```

Adds the index of `current_value` in `A` to `P` and `P_rev` for future iterations.

So, while I haven't explained why or how the algorithm works (I haven't even read the problem statement), I think that should make it clear what the C++ is doing which is what you said you're struggling with - you're on your own for the rest ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tony. This should help me figure out the algorithm